# Compare five consecutive chars on two strings

Tags: c#

I'm trying somehow to compare two strings that if among the two strings AT LEAST 5 consecutive characters are correct, if is it correct I write these on the richtextbox 3 and stop if the string is done. But I can't write it, I'm a novice
someone to help me please?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s1 = richTextBox1.Text;
            string s2 = richTextBox2.Text;

            int s1Length = s1.Length;
            int s2Length = s2.Length;

            int compteur = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s1Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < s2Length; j++)
                {
                    if (s1[i] == s2[j])
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                        {
                            if (s1[i + k] == s2[j + k])
                            {
                                compteur++;
                                if (compteur == 5)
                                {
                                    richTextBox3.Text += s1.Substring(i - compteur, i) + Environment.NewLine;
                                    compteur = 0;
                                    i += k;
                                }
                            }                          
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide some *examples*, please?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick and dirty attempt -- but you can adjust as needed.  Created a separate method to just test if first five a string matches any in a second string and iterated thorugh the first string.

Give this a try:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s1 = richTextBox1.Text;
            string s2 = richTextBox2.Text;

            for(int inx = 0; inx <= s1.Length - 5; inx++)
            {
                string s1prime = s1.Substring(inx);
                (bool found5, string foundStr) = HasCommon5(s1prime, s2);

                if (found5)
                {
                    richTextBox3.Text = foundStr;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        (bool, string) HasCommon5(string s1, string s2)
        {
            bool found5 = false;
            int s1inx = 0;
            int s2inx = 0;
            int consec = 0;

            StringBuilder foundStr = new StringBuilder("12345");

            bool canCompare = s1.Length > 4 && s2.Length > 4;
            while (canCompare && !found5)
            {
                var s1char = s1[s1inx];
                var s2char = s2[s2inx];
                if (s1char == s2char)
                {
                    foundStr[consec] = s1[s1inx];
                    consec++;
                    s1inx++;
                    s2inx++;
                }
                else
                {
                    consec = 0;
                    s2inx++;
                }
                found5 = consec > 4;
                canCompare = s1.Length - s1inx >= 5 - consec &&
                             s2.Length - s2inx >= 5 - consec;
            }

            return (found5, found5 ? foundStr.ToString(): null);
        }
```